# Cant place the image on top of the page

Tags: html, css

I am creating a site, i have placed a image on top of the page. Eventhough i have set the top margin to 0, the image is not attaching to the top. The image appears around 5px down from the top. my html and css code

```
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="header">


</div> <!-- header div -->
    <nav class='navigation main-navigation'>
        <ul class='menu main-menu'>
            <li class='menu-item'>
                <a class='three-d' href='/'>
                    <span title='Home'>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

And my css code

```
#maindiv {
width: 900px;       
margin: 0px auto;     
background: #fff url(banner.jpg) no-repeat;
```

}

```
#header {height:200px}
```

you can see there is some space on top of the image. i want the image to be on very top of the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEwLF.jpg

Comment: Try to use a reset style sheet. we can avoid these kind of problems  easily. eg : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: set background position for your pic

Comment: add `body {margin:0;}` css rule

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Chrome applies natively a margin of 8px to the `<body>` element.

Inserting the following css to your code will solve the problem:

```
html, body{
margin:0;
}
```

To keep the image centered additionally add the following to the `#maindiv` css style:

```
background-position:top center;
```

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/omzj0aar/1) demo

Comment: it works but the image moves to the left side..i need to place it center

Comment: this works with small images(the width should be more than that of the image). I got centered the image using margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; thanks for you answers.helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your code:

```
#maindiv {
width: 900px;       
margin: 0px auto;     
background: #fff url(banner.jpg) no-repeat; 
position:fixed; // or position:relative;
top:0;     
}

#header {height:200px}
```

Comment: it works but the image moves to the left side..i need to place it center

Answer (score 0):

add this in your css file

```
*{margin:0 auto; padding:0px;}
```

it will remove all default margins and padding

Comment: It works but it is a bad idea. Removing margin and padding from the body would be enough.

Comment: but why it is bad idea

Comment: To remove all margin and padding from everything.. some elements have margin by default like an `ul`. you would have to manually add the margins and paddings back to them which is unnecessary if you just remove the padding and margin from the body.